# Mqtt Service in conjunction with MqttAndroidClient

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I have an app that is using Mqtt service with notifications set up. However, the client is not receiving messages when the app is forcefully closed. I notice that there is MqttServce. How do I use it in conjunction with the Android client?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please read [ask] and provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android you can use Paho Android project, you can intialize a client.

```
MqttAndroidClient mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(BaseApplication.getAppContext(), broker, MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
```

Set required options and then subscribe to receive messages.

```
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
```

Also set following in manifest file.

```
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
</service>
```

Since the question is very high level would recommend visiting their project on GitHub and going through samples online.

[Eclipse Paho Android](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android)

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !

Comment: Hi, I have done this already, however when I swipe to close the app I stop receiving notifications. I need the ability for retrieval of notifications to persist. Should I use a service or does the client already support something like that?

Comment: If the close the app service started will be stopped but yes your messages would be persisted on the server side, so if you connect again you should receive them.

Comment: Hi, yes I have done that with the manifest as well. What if I want the ability to receive messages regardless if the app was closed? Like how whatsapp or facebook messenger does it?